# Terminal issue with export PS1=""

Tags: macos, command-line

So I tried to change the output of my terminal prompt but when I try something like /W it just puts the /W not the path.  For example `export PS1="/W $ "`turns my prompt into "/W $"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It needs to be `\W`, with a backslash.

Answer (score 5):

That should be a backslash, not a slash: `\W`.